# Show that $a$ is minimum

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $(A,<)$ totally ordered, show that if $a$ is a minimal element of $A$ then $a$ is minimum. Could you give me a hint how we could do this?

*Definitions*:

Let $(A, \leq)$ be an ordered set.
We say that $a \in A$ is:

- minimal, when it does not exist in $A$ an element that is previous of $a$ and different from it, i.e. $(\forall x \in A)(x \leq a \rightarrow x=a)$
  $$$$
- minimum when $(\forall x \in A) a \leq x$
  $$$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that $a$ satisfies the definition of *minimum*, i.e. for each $x \in A$, $a \leq x$.

Everytime you need to show a "for each", fix the element. In our case, we fix $x \in A$. We now need to show that $a \leq x$.

Because the order is total, either $a \leq x$ or $x \leq a$. Try to show $a \leq x$ in both cases and look at your assumptions if you are stuck!